# How to Enable Attachments in an Access Database that was Updated from 2002/2003 to 365

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2016

I am trying to add an option to attach a document to my database. It was originally made in Access 2002-2003, and I moved it to Access 365 and allowed it to be made compatible with 365. Everything works as it did in the old version, but I can't create an attachment field in tables or forms (it says "Operation is not supported for this type of object"). Why is this? and what can I do to fix it?

I have tried adding "attachment" to my toolbar using "customize ribbon", but it is just greyed out and I can't actually select it.

Comment: Have you converted the database from MDB to ACCDB format?

Comment: @HansUp How do you do that?

Comment: @HansUp I got it actually. Thanks